# Session and cookies are automatically destroying when form post from other website in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, php-5.6

Session and cookies are automatically destroying when form submit (post) from other website in PHP 5.6 (I can't update php versions because its a big website and existing codes are written around 10 years ago)
**Other Website Codes:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="https://www.anydomain.com/payment/c_process_payment.php?code=pass" method="post">
         <input name="asdfasdf" type="text" value="asdfasdf">
        <input type="submit" />
    
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**My Website Code:**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo "post<br>";
 var_dump($_POST);
 echo "GET<br>";
 var_dump($_GET);
 echo "session<br>";
 var_dump($_SESSION);
 echo "cookie<br>";
 var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

**.htaccess File**

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error-docs/500.shtml
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine on
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ ./CustomerHomeDetail.php?RememberCountry1=$1&RememberCityID1=$2&rest=$3&branchID=$4[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ./CustomerHomeDetail.php?RememberCountry1=$1&RememberCityID1=$2&rest=$3&branchID=$4 [L]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|ipad|android|blackberry|windows\ phone) [NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} neyiyelim\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://m.neyiyelim.net/$1 [R,L]
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software 
 # For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
  <IfModule php5_module>
  php_flag asp_tags Off
  php_flag display_errors Off
  php_value max_execution_time 30
  php_value max_input_time 60
  php_value max_input_vars 1000
  php_value memory_limit 64M
  php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
  php_value post_max_size 8M
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
  php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
  php_value date.timezone "Etc/GMT-3"
  </IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 64M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_value date.timezone "Etc/GMT-3"
 </IfModule>
  # END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

I can get session and cookies if i am not posting any data from outside URL but as i post data session and cookies just get destroyed or removed. I have increased session time and tried to find other server & php issues but could not get anything related.

Comment: Cookies are specific to a particular domain. Sessions depend on a cookie.

Comment: Please write a proper explanation of what you're doing. It's very unclear atm. Take it step by step, where are you setting the session? What are you then doing? Submitting the form to another site? When and where are you trying to read the session again? On the other site? Or does it redirect back to the first?

Comment: _Side note:_ If the code was written so long ago that you can't upgrade PHP to a supported version, then you should update the code to work with newer and supported versions. If it works in 5.6, it would probably not be _that_ much differences.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i am setting session on my website with simple $_SESSION['sess_var']='x';  when i accessing same variable with same url its working but as i post from outside url it just destroying the session

Comment: Please read my comment again. That isn't even close to enough info or what I asked for.

Comment: @Barmar I understand how cookies works but it look like wearied problem when we posting (form submit, POST) anything to my domain from any outside domain url like Payment Gateway it just clear all cookies and session